# boost library error while using message_queue and shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using shared_memory and message_queue from the boost library.

A image processing application provides parameter and 3D points in a shared_memory and a gui-application grabs the data out of the memory. The synchronisation works with message_queue's.
It works well in a short run but after a longer perdiod fatal errors occurs and also a restart does not help.
After that it's not possible to create a new shared_memory section or a message_queue. Creating a new message_queue fails with 'BOOST_ASSERT (ptr != 0)'.
A part of the init part looks like the code below (is also not working anymore):

```
//initializing default values - VoxelGrid_X
message_queue::remove("param_VX");
message_queue mq_VX(create_only, "param_VX", 1, sizeof(double));
mq_VX.try_send(&parameter_VX, sizeof(parameter_VX), 0);
ui->lineEdit_VX->setPlaceholderText(QString::number(convert_m_mm(parameter_VX)));
```

A part of reading out the parameter in the image-processing app looks like the code below:

```
//VoxelGrid: X
                            try {
                                unsigned int priority_VX = NULL;
                                message_queue::size_type recv_size_VX = NULL;
                                message_queue mq_VX(open_only, "param_VX");
                                mq_VX.try_receive(&leafSizeX, sizeof(leafSizeX), recv_size_VX, priority_VX);
                            }
                            catch (interprocess_exception &ex) {

                            }
```

What could be the problem? Does anybody have similar experiences? I would be happy to get hints about possible solutions.

Best regards,
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ... it's a weird problem, but it in that case is necessary to define the place, where the shared_memory has to be stored.
In my case:

`#define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH "C:/Shared_Memory`"